# Angularjs ui bootsrap datepicker in backbase portal not working

Tags: datepicker, angularjs-bootstrap, backbase-portal

I am trying to use datepicker of Angularjs ui boostrap in backbase portal but it is not working. Same code is working outside backbase portal.
My HTML code

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="border:0px"
            uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" 
            is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="false" show-button-bar="false"
            max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
            date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" 
            close-text="Close"  ng-click="open($event)">
              <i ><img data-ng-src="{{imageDir}}/calendar.png"/></i></button>
```

My JS code :

```
$scope.today = function() {
$scope.dt = new Date();
};
 $scope.today();
$scope.refresh = function(){
$scope.dt = new Date();
}

 $scope.maxDate  = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()));
 $scope.minDate  = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-7));

 $scope.open = function($event) {
  $scope.status.opened = true;
 };

 $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
  $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

 $scope.dateOptions = {
 formatYear: 'yy',
 startingDay: 1
 };



$scope.status = {
opened: false
};
```

I have included boostrap.min.css in my html and I have angular-ui-bootstrap js in launchpad support folder.
Can anyone please explain how to use angularjs ui boostrap components in Backbase portal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
        Can you please paste your whole HTML and JS files here. This would help to understand what dependencies your are loading.

        Can you please check if you are referencing the launchpad require conf..

        <script src="../../../launchpad/conf/require-conf.js"></script>

    Also in JS loading the launchpad angular config as below

   define([ "jquery",
             "angular",                 
             "launchpad/support/angular/angular-ui-bootstrap",
             "launchpad/lib/ui"*
            ], function($,angular){
             "use strict";
```